# VBA to sort a region by columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a VB script in Excel that will basically take all columns to the right of (or containing) the active cell and sort them left to right on row 1.

Currently, I've got:

```
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveCell.CurrentRegion, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
  End With
End Sub
```

Now, there are at least 2 problems with this: 1) I know that currentregion doesn't give me what I want, but more importantly, this gives me an error that the sort reference is not valid

Comment: Excel is designed to sort vertically, not horizontally.  Can you put the data in a column and then sort it?

Comment: actually, the .Orientation takes care of the the horizontally problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code for an example of sorting based on your needs. Note: the code sets the sort range to INCLUDE the column of the activecell.

Let us know if you need additional help adapting it, or any other questions you may have.

```
Sub SortBasedOnActiveCell()
    Dim sActive As Worksheet
    Dim rActive As Range
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim rSortRange As Range

    Set sActive = ActiveSheet
    Set rActive = ActiveCell

    'Below will work if the sheet is laid out "normally"
    'with contiguous rows and columns. If not, then consider building
    'in different business logic to determine the end of your sort range
    Set rLastCell = sActive.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    Set rSortRange = Range(sActive.Cells(1, rActive.Column), rLastCell)

    sActive.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    sActive.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Intersect(sActive.Rows(1), rSortRange), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With sActive.Sort
        .SetRange rSortRange
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```